# Check the type of a class

Tags: c#

I have the following C# classes:

```
public class Reply<T> { }

public class Ok<T> : Reply<T> { }

public class BadRequest<T> : Reply<T> { }
```

And on a method which receives a Reply I need to check it its type is Ok or BadRequest or ... Something like:

```
public static String Evaluate(Reply<T> reply) {

  switch (typeof(reply)) {
    case typeof(Ok<T>):
      // Do something
      break;
    // Other cases
  }

}
```

But I get the error

```
 The type or namespace name 'reply' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Any idea how to test the type of reply?

Comment: You also can't switch on a type.  You'll have to compare directly, or can do something like `if (reply is Ok<T>) { // Do something }`

Comment: I should also note that a situation where you're doing a `switch/case` on an object's type may actually be a good indication that it's time to add an overridable method to Reply to perform that action. If you may expect other object types, then make a shared Interface (Interface_CanDoSomethingByCase).

Comment: [Object.GetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Katana314 I understand your suggestion about override ... But in this case the Ok, BadRequest, etc are classes in a service layer. And my evaluate method is to convert those service layer responses to HTTP responses like 500, 404, 200, etc. They do not match exactly but I don't think having that HTTP functionality inside the service layer is a good option because I want it to be HTTP agnostic ... so this is why I am using this Evaluate method (or may extension) on my service layer consumer to convert the responses to HTTP responses.

Comment: @Miguel Fair enough. I've never really known how to properly reconcile good MVC design against good object-oriented design when they seem to conflict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `typeof()` only works on *types* (as in `typeof(int)`), not *variables*, so you would need

```
reply.GetType()
```

instead.

But then you'll find that `case` expressions require *literal* values, so you'll need to convert to an if-else block:

```
public static String Evaluate<T>(Reply<T> reply) {
    if(reply.GetType() == typeof(Ok<T>)) {
        // Do something
    }
    else {
     // Other cases  
    }
}
```

or

```
  if(reply is Ok<T>) {
      // Do something
  }
  else {
      // Other cases
  }
```

Comment: What is the difference between is or typeof? I suppose the first option is faster?

Comment: [`is`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) works for subclasses too, so if `reply` were an instance of a class that _inherited_ from `Ok<T>` then `is` would return true while `==` would not.  I doubt there's any significant difference in speed.

Comment: I didn't know `is` worked for subclasses. I've been using typeof(foo).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(bar)). Good answer!

Answer (score 2):

`reply.GetType()` is what you're looking for

Answer (score -1):

You can use `typeof` which is an operator that returns the `System.Type` of an Object

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx

Comment: OP _is_ using `typeof` - just using it incorrectly.

Comment: I haven't programmed C# in a while, but isn't that used to get a `System.Type` instance from a `Class`? ie, not an instance, but the class structure itself by name (`System.String`, vs `myStr`)

Comment: My mistake! Very early here just missed it.